# How to Read Large Json File in chunks

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, gson

I am using below JSON format:

```
[{object1},{object2},{object3}...]
```

I am reading a JSON file object wise means one by one (object by object) and my below code working fine.

I want to read it in chunks(at a time 10 objects). I have tried a lot but I am not getting any solution (without using Spring Batch). Can anybody please help me how to read in chunks

```
@Component
public class PdpiRunner3 implements CommandLineRunner {

    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        
            try {
            JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new ClassPathResource("/json/trades2.json").getInputStream(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            jsonReader.beginArray();
            while (jsonReader.hasNext()) { // next json array element
                PDPIfiles json = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, PDPIfiles.class);
                if (json != null) {
                    System.out.println(json);
                }

            }
            jsonReader.endArray();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Is it possible to read json element In Chunk without spring Batch pleas help ?

Comment: Parse the JSON yourself, the format looks simple enough, read from { to } and use Jackson or other library to parse the bytes as an individual object.

Comment: Your question is not about Spring Batch, why are you tagging it with `spring-batch`? I removed that tag and you re-added it. You seem to be new here, so please check this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: There is a workaround. You can add a counter with a for loop to read n objects as a chunk once a time. And then process the chunk data together.

Comment: with my code, I am able to read from { to} using Gson. but  I want to read chunks wise (means at a time to read 10 objects again remaining 10 objects like that end of this array)  @ Ironluca